# Modeling first ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckRwx.png)

I know its rate in minus rate out. Is $$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{12L}{M} - \frac{6L}{M}(\frac{X}{1000L})?$$ I know I have to find the integral of this but how do I find the amount of salt after $1.5 $ hrs?

Comment: Why are there so many $L$s and $M$s? Your equation isn't even in terms of $t$.

Comment: L represents the Liter and M represents the minutes

Comment: Okay, I see then.

Answer (score 1):

The definite integral $Q(t)$ when evaluated at $t$ gives you the amount of salt at time $t$. Therefore $Q(1.5)$ will give you the amount of salt after $1.5$ hours.

Also, you are right that you need $\text{rate in} - \text{rate out}$. There is no salt flowing in the tank, so we can just look at the rate of salt exiting. Therefore we can use the fact that $\text{concentration} = \frac{\text{amount of salt at time $t$}}{\text{volume of water at time $t$}}$.

Therefore we have to solve:
$$Q'(t) = (-6)\left(\frac{Q(t)}{1000+6t}\right), Q(0)=60$$